# How to get first column value of invoked row in table?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu

In below context menu example .. how to get value of fist column that invoked it?

[Refer Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/X9tgY/)

tried with `$(this).find('td:first').text()` but it didnt work.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can do this:

```
menuSelected: function (invokedOn, selectedMenu) {
    var value = invokedOn.parent().children(':first').text();
    var msg = "You selected the menu item '" + selectedMenu.text() +
        "' on the value '" + value + "'";
    alert(msg);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X9tgY/402/

Answer (score 1):

here its working

```
 var arr = [];
$("#myTable tr").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).find("td:first").text()); //put elements into array
});
alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
invokedOn.closest('table').find('tr td:first').text()
```

Complete code:

```
menuSelected: function (invokedOn, selectedMenu) {
        var msg = "You selected the menu item '" + selectedMenu.text() +
            "' on the value '" + invokedOn.closest('table').find('tr td:first').text() + "'";

        alert(msg);

    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X9tgY/403/)**